# Getting jQuery animate error

Tags: jquery

I try to make a text to go to right (he should appear from the left part of monitor and to go to right to a specific right (I should set it). Here is my problem, .animate function just don't work for me. I tried so many times but nothing. Here are the code:

```
           <div id="text">
         Text
       </div>

#text {
width: 700px;
color: black;
text-decoration: dashed;}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#text').animate({ right: "200px" }, 1500);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8opmde4p/

Help me, please. Thanks.

Comment: [**Include jQuery to fiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/8opmde4p/3/) and right,left,top,bottom only works with positioned elements!

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle, plus you need to set a position when animating. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8opmde4p/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `right` property does nothing because `#text` is using the default value for the [`position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): `static`. Try using `position: absolute`. In your JS, `right` should be `left` because you're moving it `200px` *from* the left.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').animate({ left: "200px" }, 1500);
});
```

```css
#text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 700px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypnyvezx/

---

If you don't want to add to change the flow by using `position: absolute`, use `padding-left` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').animate({ paddingLeft: "200px" }, 1500);
});
```

```css
#text {
    width: 700px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#text` has `position: static` by default, and so setting `right` doesn't change anything. It only applies to elements that have `position: absolute`.

If you want to move it left, try increasing the `margin-left`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8opmde4p/4/),** and code below:

```
$('#text').animate({ "margin-left": "200px" }, 1500);
```

Do you know how to debug JavaScript? As [Dhaval Marthak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157321/dhaval-marthak) rightly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448763/getting-jquery-animate-error/27448831#comment43336321_27448763), you also forgot to include jQuery in your JSFiddle.  Try opening the console (F12 on most browsers) and looking for errors in your *original* code. In my case, it said `"$ is not defined"`—that's how I found out you had forgotten to load jQuery.